# Along With Camera Zoom the rectangles should modify

Tags: math, camera, libgdx

I'm Currently working on my first game in Libgdx.I managed to do a lot but now having a problem

I have set zoom in /out effect to a grid(say 6x7 ). I want the rectangles to size accordingly. i.e. the rectangles size should increase/decrease along with camera zoom ratio.

say .. rectangle is set to(100,100,Width,Height) and camera.zoom =1 (default)

after camera.zoom=0.3  rectangle is set to same position.

i want the rectangle to transform with  zoom ratio. I cant find by how much amount i should transform. 
i dint used scene2D . i used gesturelistener for zoom

```
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance){
    float ratio = initialDistance / distance;
    camera.zoom= initialScale * ratio;
}
```

Comment: Your camera should do those transformations for you. Make sure to use camera.update() after changing the zoom level. Pls add some code to your question. Otherwise we cannot help you. Do you want to render differently, or do you have problems with the input capturing? Do you use a Stage? ...

Comment: i added my zoom code.It works fine. and m not using stage.

Comment: What **doesn't** work? What's your actual problem?

Comment: without zoom my rectangles detect touchpoints. but after zooming in/out they doesnt. i will give link of an image to make my question clear, in case u dont get it.

Comment: sry i'm new to stackoverflow also .

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not want to change your `Rectangle`s when your camera zoom changes. Cars and persons or trees also don't change their size when you use the zoom on a real camera.

What you want is to change your input coordinates according to the current zoom level. You can use [`Camera.unproject(Vector3)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29) for that purpose.

It might look like this:

```
Camera cam = ...;
Vector3 worldTouchPoint = new Vector3(touchX, touchY, 0);
cam.unproject(worldTouchPoint);
```

After that you can use worldTouchPoint to check for collisions with your (unmodified) Rectangles.